# Functional programming in Python with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, functional-programming, purely-functional

I'm interested to know how one might re-write the following function, `foo`, within the functional programming paradigm. I can't figure out how to apply `filter_df()` to columns in kwargs and store the output without changing the the value of the original DataFrame object, `df`.

```
def foo(df, **kwargs):
    for column, values in kwargs.items():
        df = filter_df(df, column, values)
    return df

def filter_df(df, column, values):
    return df.loc[df[column].isin(values)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

An obvious solution to me might be to assign a new variable, `df_new` to the output of `filter_df`, e.g.

```
def foo(df, **kwargs):
    for column, values in kwargs.items():
        df_new = filter_df(df, column, values)
    return df_new
```

However, this is not particularly memory efficient as `df` could be quite large. Also, I'm not sure if this option be would classed as purely functional because `df_new` is affected on each loop iteration.

Comment: Your `filter_df` always returns a different object, it doesn't affect the original DataFrame (`reset_index` doesn't act in-place). The two definitions of `foo` are identical in practical terms and memory-efficiency, you are just binding a different name to the DataFrame returned by `filter_df`. That is not how assignment and variables work in python, variables are just names for a  given object.

Comment: Thank you @Rodalm, I can see that `filter_df` returns a different object, which is intentional. I'm not sure I see that the two definitions of `foo` are identical. Since `df` is a mutable object, the value of the object passed into `foo` for the argument `df` will also be changed in the caller, in the first definition of `foo`. This is not the case in the second definition of `foo`.

Comment: You are right, now that I see better, they are not identical in fact. I thought you were passing `df_new` as an argument in the second case, not `df`.  But the second example does not produce the same output as the first case, it only returns the rows that respect the last condition, ignoring the other conditions. Are you aware of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear what you mean by

> re-write the following function, `foo`, within the functional programming paradigm.

and by

> However, this is not particularly memory efficient as df could be quite large. Also, I'm not sure if this option be would classed as purely functional because df_new is affected on each loop iteration.

Note that your second definition of `foo` doesn't produce the same output as the first case, it only returns the rows that respect the last condition and ignores the remaining conditions.

In each iteration, `filter_df` produces a new object (the rows of DataFrame which satisfy `df[column].isin(values)`) since `reset_index` doesn't act in-place. `df_new` is not "affected on each loop iteration", the name `df_new` is simply re-binded (i.e. points to) to a new object in each iteration. The conditions are being applied separately, only the DataFrame resulting from the last one is returned.

**Solution**

In this particular case, `foo` can be simplified using [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html). This way you don't create unnecessary intermediate DataFrames.

```
def foo(df, **kwargs):
    query = ' and '.join(f'{col} in {vals}' for col, vals in kwargs.items())
    return df.query(query)
```

Comment: @nick I updated my answer. Does it solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks @Rodalm. I see what you're saying re. the second definition of `foo`. My mistake. Nice idea with the simplification. However it is not equivalent to the first definition: the use of `all` requires all of the column values for a given row to be `True`, i.e. there must be a `kwarg` for every column, which is not the case in the original implementation. Unfortunately, changing to `any` doesn't work either. The original implementation filters any row  for which the columns, specified in the keys of `kwargs`, does not contain the corresponding value.

Comment: A rather "hacky" implementation that does seem to work, utilising your neat one liner, is: `def foo(df, kwargs**): ;   for column in df.columns: ;  if not column in kwargs.keys(): ; kwargs[column] = list(df[column]) ; return df[df.isin(kwargs).all(axis=1)]` (sorry I can't seem to format code snippets in comments).

Comment: @nick You are right, my bad! I updated my solution, using `DataFrame.query` works as you desire and is more elegant than using those hacky tricks ;)

Comment: I love it. You really know your pandas! Seems to work with my limited testing. I feel it makes more sense to me to have `f'{vals} in {col}' for col, vals in kwargs.items()`, but I'm not familiar with the `query` method. I'm guessing `{col}` gets evaluated to a list containing all the values in `df[col]`? I also believe this solves the original issue of creating a purely function function, i.e. avoids the need to change the value of any object.

Comment: @nick I am happy to help! That's exactly it. [This official guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#the-query-method) may help you learn more about the `query` method